# Does Zbox AD03 work fine with Ubuntu and XBMC?

Tags: hdmi, xbmc, blu-ray

I have a Zotac ZBOX AD03 (bluray) currently installed with Windows. I would like to pass to Linux and I would like to try Ubuntu.

Does anybody of you has hints / tips / warning to provide?

Is the combination ZBOX AD03 + Ubuntu + XBMC working smoothly?

What about HDMI and Bluray interfaces? Are they easily managed and recognized?

Answer (score 0):

This guide is written for the AD02 but it works for the AD03 as well (it also works for my fusion based netbook), it is very complete:
http://youresuchageek.blogspot.nl/2012/06/xbmc-install-and-config-howto-for-linux.html
You can choose for yourself if you want a minimal installation (no desktop, just xbmc) or normal installation (desktop, with the option to start xbmc)

EDIT: A bit of a warning, the guide can be rather technical, just install the normal ubuntu and install xbmc, see what happens. If you're a bit more experienced with ubuntu (or just a bit more adventerous :P) follow the guide.